# Enable i.mx6 "Force_recov" mode through userspace?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded, embedded-linux

I am working with Freescale i.mx6 SoC, using buildroot to build custom u-boot, linux kernel, and rootfs images.

Freescale offers a manufacturing tool (MfgTool2) that can write these system images to the device's eMMC via USB.  In order for this tool to work, the device must have booted in **Force_recov** mode.

For development, we can enter this mode by applying a jumper to two pins.  My question is, is there a way to enable Force_recov mode through userspace (or, "software" enable)?

The end goal is to provide a way for users to upgrade the device using MfgTool2-based software, without having to physically apply a jumper.

Comment: Is the hardware already set in stone, or might it be possible to add some hardware to simulate this jumper being closed?

Comment: @duskwuff It can be changed if absolutely necessary.  This could be worked around entirely by handling image upgrades similar to http://stackoverflow.com/a/18219855/1730078 via USB thumb drive, but I'm curious if this is possible as an alternative/backup plan.